# Error with routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a link

```
<a href="{{ route('projects.postProject', $project->id) }}" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Post Project
</a>
```

Within my route file I have the following

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/postProject', array('as' => 'projects.postProject', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@postProject'));
```

And within the controller I have this

```
public function postProject(Project $project)
{
    dd($project);
}
```

From what I see this is correct.  However, I am getting the following

> `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in `RouteCollection.php` line 218:

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Route::post to Route::get

Comment: I know that get works, but doesnt that go against convention?  Theoretically I am posting something to another system via an API.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a link to call that route, and that's a GET request. You would need to submit a form in order to create a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You using ajax for post? In that case Route::post is correnct.

MethodNotAllowedHttpException means that you trying to use instead post something else

Show me the posting form

Comment: I am not using a form or Ajax.  Essentially, I send a Project object to my show view.  Within that view, I have the button shown in my op.  I need to send that project to a function so I can perform an API action on it.  It works with get, and my function gets the project, just wasnt sure if this was the right context though?